# integrate vs code with webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, webpack-style-loader

right now I start serving the application using `webpack-dev-server`.

Now If I make any code change in `VS Code` which causes the build failure the `webpack-dev-server` will rerun and report the failure, but I dont get to see those in VS Code.

I can use the `VS Code` typescript template to do that, but then its like multiple parallel compilation will happen for same code base.

Hence how can I integrate `webpack-dev-server` with `vs-code` to get compilation issues linked with vs-code

Answer (score 0):

in .vscode/launch.json (add below code for webpack-4):

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "build",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli",
  "args": [
    "--config",
    "webpack.config.prod.js"
  ],
  "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
  "stopOnEntry": true
}
```